# How to file flight plan with ZZZZ?

Tags: flight-planning

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ICAO_airport_code) mentions,

> ZZZZ is a pseudo-code, used in flight plans for aerodromes with no ICAO code assigned.

How pilot actually file this flight plan? Is there anything special to do when file for ZZZZ.

Comment: Or things that aren't even aerodromes to begin with -- such as a farmer's field or a parking lot.  (Especially useful for helicopter types)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know if you're asking about a specific country, but in the US it seems that you can just use it in place of a regular airport identifier and add supporting information in the remarks.

Specifically, [the AIM 5-1](https://www.faa.gov/air_traffic/publications/atpubs/aim_html/chap5_section_1.html) has several references to it, including:

> (b) If no four-letter location indicator has been assigned to the
>   departure aerodrome, insert ZZZZ and specify the non-ICAO location
>   identifier, or fix/radial/distance from a nearby navaid, followed by
>   the name of the aerodrome, in Item 18, following characters DEP/,
>
> (c) Then, without a space, insert the estimated off-block time.
>   ***EXAMPLE-***
>
> 1. KSMF2215
> 2. ZZZZ0330

The same wording is used for both FAA and ICAO flight plan instructions.